# Need fix json format

Tags: python, json

please help with my json code

I was tired of trying every way XD

```
phone = input("phonone : ")
passw = input("password: ")
json = {"act_type":"phone","password":"password","msisdn":phone}
```

i want json output like this :

```
{"act_type":"phone","password":"Salafi332","msisdn":62812****362}}
```

Comment: `{"act_type": phone,"password": passw,"msisdn":phone}`

Comment: i want passw with " "
if im not put  " " will return error requests

Comment: you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use format strings check it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp)

It would be like this:

```
phone = input("phonone : ")
passw = input("password: ")
json = {"act_type":"phone","password":f"{passw}","msisdn":phone}
```

**OR**

```
phone = input("phonone : ")
passw = input("password: ")
json = {"act_type":"phone","password":"{0}".format(passw),"msisdn":phone}
```